# Change string in graphic

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to draw string in graphic and also change it. Is there any way I can get the Text and change it? Like this one:

```
Graphics G;
G = Picture1.CreateGraphics();
/* ... */
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
{
   G.DrawString(textbox1.text, ...);
}
else
{
   G.DrawString(textbox2.text, ...);
}
```

Comment: Can anyone translate `cheng` for me?

Comment: If your goal is to do something similar to Photoshop, you need to build up layering first.

Answer (score 3):

No - once you've drawn the string, it's no longer really text. You should potentially keep a copy of "the image with no text on it" and draw on that "fresh" image each time.